# Calculating missing values when the combined mean is given.

Tags: statistics

**There are 150 workers in a factory running two shifts. The average wage of workers is Rs. 41.12. The average wage of worker in morning shift is Rs 43 and that of evening shift is Rs 35. Find out the number of workers in morning and that of evening shift.**

I calculated the answer and it comes out to be 114.75 for the number of workers working in the morning shift. The book's answer says 94 and 56 workers working in morning and evening shifts respectively. Which is the correct one? And how to go about calculating it?

I used the standard formula. The one which is used to calculate the combined mean. And tried to calculate the value for the respective variables.

[image: combined mean formula]

Comment: Are you really asking why **114.75** number of persons is incorrect?

Comment: The equation given by the formula, along with $n_1+n_2=150$, are two linear equations with two unknowns, and should be easy to solve. I'm curious as to how you obtained $114.75$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

$$\dfrac{114.75\times 43 + 35.25 \times 35}{150} = \dfrac{6168}{150} = 41.12$$
$$\dfrac{94\times 43 + 56 \times 35}{150} =\dfrac{6002}{150} \approx 40.01$$

Quite evidently you are correct (despite detractors who apparently didn't bother to check the math themselves).

Likely there is some typo in the problem statement.